# docker client (docker 1.12/centos) http: server gave HTTP response to HTTPS client

Tags: http, docker

Set up docker 1.12 on centos 7. 
docker was started using systemd with the following commandline (according to systemctl status docker):

```sh
/usr/bin/dockerd -D --tls=false --tlscert=/var/docker/server.pem --tlskey=/var/docker/serverkey.pem -H tcp://10.10.2.1:2376
```

then I want to check on the local machine, setting the following environment variables:

```sh
DOCKER_HOST=tcp://10.10.2.1:2376
DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY=0
DOCKER_MACHINE_NAME=default
```

Then checking with the docker commandline tool:

```sh
docker --tls=false --tlsverify=false  images
```

results in:

> An error occurred trying to connect: Get
>   https://10.10.2.1:2376/v1.24/images/json: http: server gave HTTP
>   response to HTTPS client

Whereas a quick check:

```sh
curl http://10.10.2.1:2376/images/json
```

gives the images info.

Now: I assume the server does respond to http, (which was intended), but how to get the client to talk http as well ?

Comment: You might check the ```iptables``` or ```firewalld``` on Centos7. They should allow ```TCP``` on port ```2376```.

Comment: @Rudi Same problem for me. Do you find any solution ?

Comment: I got my solution from: https://github.com/docker/distribution/issues/1874 (rmorales-iaa's answer)

Answer (score 0):

It needs to explicitly define that your registry is not secure:

- open */etc/docker/daemon.json* file
- add your registry to insecure-list

```js
{
  ..
  "insecure-registries" : [
    "10.10.2.1:2376"
  ],
  ..
}
```

- restart Docker-service

```sh
sudo service docker restart
```

see for details [Docker: Test an insecure registry](https://docs.docker.com/registry/insecure/)

Answer (score -3):

Port 2376 is for TLS communication.
Use port 2375 instead.

```
DOCKER_HOST=tcp://10.10.2.1:2375
```

Comment: Running docker daemon on 2375 port doesn't change anything.